# Kendo Mobile - Submit Entire Form

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have a kendo mobile form that I will be using to capture some information from my users.

I would like to post the data to a web service or aspx(test page) using ajax. It seems like overkill to use MVVM for a form that the user fills out and there will be no reads/updates/deletes.

The ajax call happens but I cannot figure out how to post the data .  Nothing goes over if i use $(this).serialize().  If I hard code some data, then it works.
There are going to be a lot of controls on the page and i hope i don't have to manually build the form data.  I cannot add a `<form>` tag as it breaks the styling of the page.

If there is a more "kendo" way of doing this please show me how. Thanks

Here is what I have so far.

```
//Submit Form 
function submit_form(e) {


        $.post('TestPost.aspx', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            // This is executed when the call to web service was succesful.
            // 'data' contains the response from the request
            alert(data);

        }).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, request, error) {
            alert('xrs.status = ' + xhr.status + '\n' +
                     'thrown error = ' + thrownError + '\n' +
                     'xhr.statusText = ' + xhr.statusText + '\n' +
                     'request = ' + request + '\n' +
                     'error = ' + error);
        });


        e.preventDefault();

    }



 //Example of html controls

 <div id="checks" data-role="view" data-title="Foo" data-layout="checklayout">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
        <li>Floor
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="Foo">
                    <input type="radio" name="Foo" id="FooOk" value="Ok" />
                    Ok</label>

            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Foo2">
                    <input type="radio" name="Foo" id="FooNotOk" value="NotOk" />
                    Not Ok</label>

            </li>
            <li id="Comment1" class="divComment" style="display: none;">
                <label>
                    Comments
                 <input type="text"  name="TextComment" id="TextComment" placeholder="Type Comments" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" />
                </label>

            </li>
            <li id="C1" class="divComment" style="display: none;">
                <label>
                    Charges
                <select id="Charges" name="Charges" >
                    <option value="nc">test</option>
                </select>
                </label>


            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
        <li>Picture
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        Select a Photo
                    <input type="file" id="kitFile" style="display: none;" />
                        <a data-role="button" data-click="select" style="float: right;">Select</a>
                    </label>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>


//Submit button
 <a data-align="right" data-role="button" class="nav-button" data-click="submit_form">Save</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here $(this) will give u only the button element. The easy way to do this is use the built in MVVM feature in Kendo UI Mobile. create an model as JS object and set data-model attribute of your view as this object. Now on click of the submit button, just send this object to your server using ajax. This way u are reducing the amount of data sent to the server.

Documentation on mobile and mVVM integration: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/mvvm .

Answer (score 1):

I have used a PageMethod previously.
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Would something like this help your cause?

Let's take an example of such a method in the code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MyMethod(string Id)
{
    return string.Format("Thanks for calling me with id: " + Id);
}
```

Things to note: the method must be static and decorated with the [WebMethod] attribute.

And on the client side you could invoke this method using the jQuery.ajax() function like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'default.aspx/MyMethod',
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ ID : ID }),
    success: function (result) { 
        alert(result.d);
    } 
});
```

Make sure that in your WebForm you have actually added reference to the jQuery library before using it.
 For example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```